# Error inflating class android widget checkbox

Tags: android, android-theme

[image]

This is my xml infected code..

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#331c57"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/gappshapp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/threedots" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Activation"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="#331c57"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="An Activation Code was Sent to your Mobile Device, Enter the code below"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="250210"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkIos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I agree with the Terms and Conditions" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/continuebtn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

it crashes when i changes my theme

i also uses the appcompat-v7 as a library and android support v7 appcompat and android support v4 jar as library but still it crash

this is my xml code,there is not code in activity,i just working on xml file and and it crashes at checkbox
during inflating class android widget checkbox...

i don't know whats happening here, i need solution for it.

Comment: have you declare this activity in AndroidMenifest ?

Comment: put your activity code and layout with error code

Comment: you need to provide code.

Comment: there is nothing in activity code  and i also declare this activity into mainfest.

Comment: Please Providence more detailed description. We need better context: layout and activity source code, an exception that beeing thrown...

Comment: there is my all xml code and nothing is in activity code...

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gappshapp/com.example.gappshapp.ActivationScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class android.widget.CheckBox ==> Logcat Values @tommus

Comment: What is a package name of Your activity? Is it `com.example.gappshapp`? Inconsistency in packages naming may cause this kind of errors.

Comment: package com.example.gappshapp;  this is my package name @tommus

Comment: The style You're applying (that causes problems) comes from SDK or it is implemented by You?

Comment: <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>   this is style class

Comment: so whats the solution fo it? @tommus

Comment: Can you pls remove the style and run your project.

Comment: Please show your entire stack trace. There is probably a nested Exception in there that gives more information on what is actually going wrong.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi   here is code of line 112 of xml     <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkIos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I agree with the Terms and Conditions" />

Comment: i have the same issue?

Comment: As @barq said, please attach entire stacktrace so we can go further with debugging.

Comment: but there is no code in activity class, there is only xml code

Comment: I mean entire stacktrace not source code. On the image at the top of the post You've attached only part of the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem today.
If I use the following:

`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

and try and use `import android.widget.CheckBox;`
with a standard checkbox:
`private CheckBox mSendSMSNotification;`
it also fails with the same error.

Converting to:
`import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;`
`private AppCompatCheckBox mSendSMSNotification;`

and also in XML: 
`<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send SMS Notification when Reports Emailed"
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxSendSMSNotification"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2" />`

resolves the error, but I dont know why.
My min API 16, target API 23